# How to apply geoNear with mongoose and get distance between two coordinates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking for a solution to retrieve docs from my collection by applying a query in Node. The Purpose is to retrieve the distance between two coordinates. It can be implemented using Native MongoDb but i want to get results with mongoose. How do i do that ?

Comment: Why would you think there is any difference? Mongoose is just a layer of convenience methods largely based around "schema validation" and some other helpers, most notably `.populate()` which really just performs an `$in` query and interpolates the matched data into retrieved documents from another query. Naturally all operations are simply passed through to the MongoDB server. So it's not like there is any difference worth noting here.

Comment: You can use either aggregation [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) or the command [`geoNear`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.geoNear) for which mongoose has a wrapper method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `geoNear` method from mongoose is used as following:

```
Model.geoNear([1,3], { maxDistance : 5, spherical : true }, function(err, results, stats) {
   console.log(results);
});

// geoJson
var point = { type : "Point", coordinates : [9,9] };
Model.geoNear(point, { maxDistance : 5, spherical : true }, function(err, results, stats) {
   console.log(results);
});
```